# Python Selenium: Stale Element Reference Exception Error

Tags: python, loops, selenium, webdriver

The issue I'm facing lies in the iteration of these loops, once the first file is downloaded from the webpage I receive an error:

"selenium.common.exceptions.StaleElementReferenceException: Message: The element reference of stale: either the element is no longer attached to the DOM or the page has been refreshed"

The "97081 data-extension xml" is the 2nd downloadable file in the iteration. I've hereby attached the code, any suggestions to rectify this will be much appreciated.

```
import os
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

fp = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()

fp.set_preference("browser.download.folderList", 2)
fp.set_preference("browser.download.manager.showWhenStarting", False)
fp.set_preference("browser.download.dir", "F:\Projects\Poli_Map\DatG_Py_Dat")
fp.set_preference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk", "text/xml")

driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile=fp)

driver.get('https://data.gov.in/catalog/variety-wise-daily-market-prices-data-cauliflower')
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)

allelements = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//a[text()='xml']")

for element in allelements:
    element.click()
    class FormPage(object):
        def fill_form(self, data):
            driver.execute_script("document.getElementById('edit-download-reasons-non-commercial').click()")
            driver.execute_script("document.getElementById('edit-reasons-d-rd').click()")
            driver.find_element_by_xpath('//input[@name = "name_d"]').send_keys(data['name_d'])
            driver.find_element_by_xpath('//input[@name = "mail_d"]').send_keys(data['mail_d'])
            return self

        def submit(self):
            driver.execute_script("document.getElementById('edit-submit').click()")

    data = {
        'name_d': 'xyz',
        'mail_d': 'xyz@outlook.com',
    }
    time.sleep(5)
    FormPage().fill_form(data).submit()

    time.sleep(5)
    window_before = driver.window_handles[0]
    driver.switch_to_window(window_before)
    driver.back()
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Once page refreshed after you call `submit()` webElements inside `allelements` are no more valid

Instead of

```
allelements = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//a[text()='xml']")

for element in allelements:
    element.click()
```

try

```
allelements = len(driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//a[text()='xml']"))

for index in range(allelements):
    driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//a[text()='xml']")[index].click()
```

Comment: Thank you Andersson, for the timely response. This works fine.

Comment: this doesn't work for me. After the click, I use `driver.execute_script("window.history.go(-1)") ` to go back to the previous page. I got **"IndexError: list index out of range"** when click the next item.

Comment: @Heinz , this seem to be a timing issue: when you get back there are no elements yet... try to implement [ExplicitWait](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html#explicit-waits)

Comment: @Andersson I implemented the wait, but still get the same error no matter how long the `timeout` is set. It appears that the driver can not focus on the page with the links after  `driver.execute_script("window.history.go(-1)")`.

Comment: does it work differently with `driver.back()`? You can submit new ticket regarding this issue as there is not enough info to provide you with a good solution

Comment: This answer saved me a lot of headache. Thanks so much for this.

Answer (score 0):

```
>>>Customize the for loop as:  

from selenium.common import exceptions  

and customize your code of for loop as:  

for element in allelements:
   try:  
     //your code to find element and operations with that element
   except exceptions.StaleElementReferenceException:  
        pass
```